# While loop not equal command not found

Tags: linux, bash, variables, while-loop

I am trying to perform a simple while loop comparing a variable to a string. It fails to load with the error on this line. Error states [: missing `]' and : command not found. My while loop looks like;

```
mainMenuInput = ""
while ["$mainMenuInput" != "Q" || "$mainMenuInput" != "q"]
do
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a couple of errors:

```
mainMenuInput="" 
while [ "$mainMenuInput" != "Q" ] && [ "$mainMenuInput" != "q" ]
```

See that variable declaration do need to be like `var=value`. Otherwise, bash would interpret that you want to perform the `var` command with `=` and `value` as parameters:

```
mainMenuInput="" 
             ^
             no spaces around =
```

In the `while` you need to put spaces around the brackets. Also, note that you need to use `&&` (and) instead of `||` (or), because otherwise it won't ever exit the `while`.

```
while [ "$mainMenuInput" != "Q" ] && [ "$mainMenuInput" != "q" ]
       ^                          ^^                          ^
   space                   it has to be AND               space
```

In fact, the condition can be rewritten to something like:

```
while [[ "$mainMenuInput" != [qQ] ]]
```

Comment: plus `-o` instead `||` or `-a` instead `&&` when used inside `[]`

Comment: Thanks, @herby but POSIX recommends the use of && and || with the single bracket notation over -a and -o.

Comment: Thanks a lot guys, I didn't know you had to have no spaces around the '=' thanks. Does what i needed it to now thanks. Also @herby using -o did work for displaying the contents for the do thanks.

Comment: @Seatter variables are set with `var=value` expression, without any space around `=`. Otherwise, bash would interpret that you want to perform the `var` command with `=` and `value` parameters.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using **bash** I think the correct syntax is:

```
    while [ $variable -ne "q" || $variable -ne "Q" ];
```